# How to call a VIEW (Not a PARTIAL VIEW) from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which contains a table and this table is clickable. When I click on a row, I want the detail of that row to show. The definition of this detail is in a VIEW. I do not want to use Partial Views, as I have had numerous issues with it, especially around my css/grid lapyouts. Hence I want to return a VIEW. I am unable to return a VIEW though. Please can someone assist me to return a VIEW. Below is my jquery. NB. I have even tried to do a 'POST' method, but with no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $('#dTable').DataTable();

     $('#dTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var tID = $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text());

        // var creationDate = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text();
        var self = this;
        $.ajax(
                 {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Tr/AllTrDetail",
                    data: { trID: tID },
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (data) {
                       $(self).off('click');
                    }
                 });
     });

     $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $(".dTable").dataTable({
           "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
           "iDisplayLength": 10,
           "bDestroy": true,
           "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
        }).after('<br />');
     });

  });
</script>
```

Thanks
Naren

Comment: you should make an ajax call to the **action method which returns the view**. Your code is calling `AllTrDetail` method. Have it return the view/partial view.

Comment: If you want to display the view data in your page, shouldn't you be inserting it into your DOM in the success function? Something like `$('#output').html(data);`?

Comment: Yes, AllTrDetail is a method in Controller Tr .. it is a Get method which returns a VIEW() ..

Comment: Ive replaced  $(self).off('click'); with $('#output').html(data); .. but im not getting any VIEW being displayed .. am I doing anything wrong? I am on debug mode and I do see that the method in the controller being called and get no errors. It does reach the return VIEW .. so am not sure what else to do ..

Comment: couple of things you could try: if you call page from browser address bar, do you get the results you expect? (you might need to view source to check, since I'm assuming you are returning an html fragment). Also, might be good to check the network panel in your browser dev tools (f12). You would need to have the network panel open before your ajax call...it generally only logs when it's open. Sounds like the problem is on the server side...these two tests could help to verify.

Comment: Ok, if I call the page directly from my address bar, its all good. When in my 'header' VIEW, which has my clickable table, I click on a row. In debug mode, it takes me to the controller, and all my breakpoints go through successfully. I also have a breakpoint in the calling 'detail' VIEW, which is attached to, @using (Html.BeginForm()) .. And it goes into this point, but the called detail VIEW still doesn't show. I still see the first VIEW. I 'view Source', and I only see the first header VIEW .. Can Ajax return a normal VIEW ? It looks like it can only return Partial VIEWS?

Comment: I think it has to do with the following code, as the return success is not giving me the VIEW :                                success: function (data) {
                                                                          $('#output').html(data);
                                                                      }